Portfolio sorting and Fama-MacBeth regression
I have often heard that portfolio sorting is closely related to Fama-MacBeth regression. And also terms like "pure-play portfolios". I dont think I understand it.
For example, lets sorts stocks based on book-to-market ratios into 10 portfolios. we can get HML returns. what is the connection to the FM regression coefficient where we regress stock returns on BM ratios?

Maybe the connection is only to the first stage of the Fama-MacBeth procedure where you do the sorting into portfolios?

I think there is more to it

Two points: have a look at Cochrane's 2011 JF 'Discount Rates' paper regarding how portfolio sorts and regressions are the same. Then, also look at Fama and French's 2020 RFS paper. They refer back to an old result from Fama in the 1970s that FM regression slopes/intercepts are just returns on certain portfolios. That property makes FM really elegant: it's just a portfolio sort in the end.

Wonderful! Thanks a lot Kevin
